# Why does my anchor tag not work when I add ? after the anchor

Tags: php, html, tags

I'm trying to send users to a certain page of my website that uses anchors on the page.

i.e `thispage.co.uk/index#tab-1?campaign=email`

the anchor tag works when there is no `?campaign=email`

Is there a way to make the anchor tag work with the ? after it

Comment: Welcome. Try `thispage.co.uk/index?campaign=email#tab-1`. The hash mark `#` is an optional _last_ part of a URL for a document

Comment: Works perfect!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you have to place the get data **BEFORE** your anchor.

Try this

```
page.co.uk/index?campaign=email#tab-1
```

As said by kerbholz, hash mark is an optional last part of a url.

Comment: What does this mean, can you explain a little more please

Comment: Try thispage.co.uk/index?campaign=email#tab-1. As said by kerbholz, hash mark is an optional last part of a url.

Comment: No not to me. Put that INTO your ANSWER